# MQTT Load Testing using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, load-testing, mosquitto

I want to perform load testing of my MQTT Broker (Mosquitto) along with my Client application for concurrent connections. I am using MQTT plugin [mqtt-jmeter](https://github.com/emqx/mqtt-jmeter), but the problem here is I cannot send different (varying) payloads for each request. Also I cannot change topic names for each request.
Can anyone suggest how to test concurrent connections with varying payloads and topic names for each connection?

Comment: "You get what you paid for" as usual. Fire-and-forget test tools don't let you change things much. We wrote a little blog post about it https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2018/09/fire-and-forget-vs-complete-control-of.html